# Date to Begin Asking for Rain in the Diaspora

Tags: tefilla

In the US we usually start asking for rain in the amida on the
fourth of December at night. The halacha states that this is on
the sixtieth days of tekufat Tishri (the fall season). But the
fall season falls usually around September twenty one. There is
a difference of about two weeks. Why?

Comment: Related question that might help: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11985/praying-for-rain-in-the-diaspora/11991#11991

Comment: https://www.amazon.com.au/Seasons-Soul-Historical-Philosophical-Perspectives/dp/0899068529 has a chapter on this, as far as I remember.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#cite_ref-5) will help

Comment: @yydl or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98187/759

Comment: It is because of the difference between the Julian and Gregorian calendars. Once the Sanhedrin is reestablished, the date will be set by the Sanhedrin.

Comment: @sabbahillel is that true? Why would it change? Because the tekufos are slowly becoming inacurate?

Comment: @robev The calendar used is basically the Julian calendar which has three extra leap years every 400 years. As an example, when the switch was made in England, 15 days were removed from the calendar. Thus when the Gregorian calendar skips a leap year (years divided by 100 but not 400 at the end of each century) the discrepancy grows by one day. Thus, this century had a leap year in 2000 but skipped in 1900 and will skip again in 2100.